# Making a field readonly in Django Admin, based on another field's value

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

How to make a field in Django Admin readonly or non-editable based on the value from another field?
I have used `readonly_fields=('amount',)` but this wont fix my problem , as I need to manage it based on another field .

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can override the admin's `get_readonly_fields` method:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj and obj.another_field == 'cant_change_amount':
            return self.readonly_fields + ('amount',)
        return self.readonly_fields
```

Comment: Can this be done while maintaing the field ordering?

Answer (score 1):

For filling out one field from another, you need to add a `prepopulated_fields` attribute to the relevant `ModelAdmin` class. For example:

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}
```

The relevant documentation can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.prepopulated_fields).

However, in the version of django I'm using at the moment (1.3), this seems to create an  error when `readonly_fields` is also used.

Answer (score 0):

Declare any permanently readonly_fields in the body of the class, as the readonly_fields class attribute will be accessed from validation