# Make the prepopulated slug field as readonly in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, readonly, slug

I want to make the slug field as read_only depending on the other field value like "lock_slug".

Means There will be Two conditions.

1) When value of "lock_slug" is false then the slug field directly prepopulated from the field "title".

```
prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",),}
```

2) When value of "lock_slug" is true then the slug field make as readonly.

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj = None):
    if obj and obj.lock_slug == True:
        return ('slug',) + self.readonly_fields        
    return self.readonly_fields
```

These two works fine independently, but problematic when used both.

Means when I try to add get_readonly_fields() on edit then it gives error because of prepopulated_fields.These two crashes with each other.

There will be any solution for working both on admin side.

I also refer below links

[Making a field readonly in Django Admin, based on another field's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601148/making-a-field-readonly-in-django-admin)

[django admin make a field read-only when modifying obj but required when adding new obj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343535/django-admin-make-a-field-read-only-when-modifying-obj-but-required-when-adding)

But not working these two at the same time.

Thanks,

Meenakshi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can not make the prepoluted field as read_only. So I create the new field which is not prepopulated and perform the action on that field and my problem get solved.

Comment: The new answer to this question is the better solution.

Answer (score 8):

Here is another way:

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'title',
        'slug',
    )
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj:
            self.prepopulated_fields = {}
            return self.readonly_fields + ('slug',)
        return self.readonly_fields
```

Comment: In 2016, this doesn't work. If field is readonly, that means it wouldn't show, and prepopulated field will have nothing to prepopulate to. I get a `u"Key 'slug' not found in 'theModelForm'.`

Comment: In 2021, this worked and solved my issue :)

Answer (score 2):

As @Rexford pointed out, the most voted answer doesn't work for recent django versions, since you can't make readonly a prepopulated field.

By the way, you can still get what you want, just override also the `get_prepopulated_fields` method using the same logic, i.e:

```
class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {
        'slug': ('title', ),
    }


    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        readonly_fields = super().get_readonly_fields(request, obj)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return readonly_fields
        return list(readonly_fields) + ['slug', ]

    def get_prepopulated_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        prepopulated_fields = super().get_prepopulated_fields(request, obj)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return prepopulated_fields
        else:
            return {}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a brilliant solution! I added `super()` in play, so changes and updates to the parent method are taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

### Mar, 2022 Update:

You cannot use **"prepopulated_fields"** with **"readonly_fields"** or **"exclude"** setting the same field **"slug"** as shown below because there is a confliction between them, then you will get error.

**"prepopulated_fields"** with **"readonly_fields"** setting the same field **"slug"**:

```py
@admin.register(Page)
class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ['title']} # "slug" field is set
    readonly_fields = ['slug'] # "slug" field is set
```

**"prepopulated_fields"** with **"exclude"** setting the same field **"slug"**:

```py
@admin.register(Page)
class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ['title']} # "slug" field is set
    exclude = ['slug'] # "slug" field is set
```

Moreover, with **"prepopulated_fields"** set **"slug" field**, you cannot use **"fields"** not set **"slug" field** as shown below because there is also a confliction between them, then you will get error:

```py
@admin.register(Page)
class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ['title']} # "slug" field is set
    fields = ['title'] # "slug" field is not set
```

Moreover again, you cannot use **"prepopulated_fields" set **"slug" field** in **"admin.py"** in this case you set **"editable=False"** to **"slug" field** in **"models.py"** because again, there is a confliction between them:

**"prepopulated_fields"** in **"admin.py"**:

```py
@admin.register(Page)
class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ['title']} # "slug" field is set
```

**"editable=False" in **"models.py"****

```py
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255) # "editable=False" is set
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, editable=False)
```

Moreover again and again, **"prepopulated_fields"** with **"get_readonly_fields()"** and **"get_prepopulated_fields()"** doesn't work:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import (
    Page,
)

@admin.register(Page)
class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ['title']}

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        readonly_fields = super().get_readonly_fields(request, obj)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return readonly_fields
        return list(readonly_fields) + ['slug']

    def get_prepopulated_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        prepopulated_fields = super().get_prepopulated_fields(request, obj)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return prepopulated_fields
        else:
            return {}
```

So finally, I found it harmful to use **"prepopulated_fields"** so I recommend not to use **"prepopulated_fields"**. So for now, my best solution is generating **"slug"** automatically without using **"prepopulated_fields"** as shown below.

First, add **"editable=False"** to **"slug" field** in **"Page" model** in **"models.py"**:

```py
                                     # "editable=False" is set
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, editable=False)
```

Then, add this code below to **"Page" model** in **"models.py"**:

```py
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify(self.title)
    super(Page, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This is the full code of **"Page" model** in **"models.py"**:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify

class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, editable=False) 
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Page, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then, as you can see below, **"slug" field** doesn't appear(is hidden) in **Add page** in the form:

[image]

But no worries!! When you fill **"Title" field** and click on **"Save"**, **"slug"** is automatically generated:

[image]

You can check if **"slug"** is automatically generated or not by adding this code to **"admin.py"**:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Page

@admin.register(Page)
class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'slug']
```

Now, you can see **the slug "this-is-my-page-1"** is generated automatically:

[image]

In addition, if you remove **"editable=False"** from **"slug" field** in **"Page" model** in **"models.py"**:

```py
                        # "editable=False" is removed
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)
```

**"slug" field** appears:

[image]

Then, when you fill **"Title" field** and click on **"Save"**, you are asked to fill **"slug" field** which means **"slug" is not automatically generated**:

[image]

So to automatically generate **"slug"**, you need to hide **"slug" field** from the form by adding **"editable=False"** to **"slug" field**:

```py
                                        # Important to hide "slug" field
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, editable=False)
```

In addition, you can hide **"slug" field** from the form by adding **"exclude = ['slug']"** or **"fields = ['title']"** to **"PageAdmin" class** in **"admin.py"**.

**"exclude = ['slug']"**:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Page

@admin.register(Page)
class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'slug']
    exclude = ['slug'] # Here
```

**"fields = ['title']"**:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Page

@admin.register(Page)
class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'slug']
    fields = ['title'] # Here
```

And in this case you add **"exclude = ['slug']"** or **"fields = ['title']"** to **"PageAdmin" class** in **"admin.py"**, you can remove **"editable=False"** from **"slug" field**:

```py
                        # "editable=False" is removed
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)
```

Finally, you can hide **"slug" field** from the form by adding **"exclude = ['slug']"** or **"fields = ['title']"** to **"PageAdmin" class** in **"admin.py"** without adding **"editable=False"** to **"slug" field**:

[image]

Then, you fill **"Title" field** and click on **"Save"**:

[image]

Then, **the slug "this-is-my-page-2"** is automatically generated:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution using HTML5's `readonly` input element attribute. Here's an example:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class Example(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

from .models import Example


class ExampleModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Example
        fields = "__all__"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["slug"].widget.attrs.update({"readonly": "1"})
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .forms import ExampleModelForm
from .models import Example


@admin.register(Example)
class ExampleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ExampleModelForm
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("name",)}
```